# what does the fatls output on uboot terminal show

Tags: u-boot

I am using a iMX8 processor. I am stopping the Uboot to check what files are present in the fat32 system. it shows the output of the name of the file present but what does the number preceding it mean?

Comment: Your question is very vague. What is the output of error? Any screenshot? Any configuration information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we trace through the code a bit we get down to `fs/fs.c` and `fs_ls_generic`, with:

```
        while ((dent = fs_readdir(dirs))) {
                if (dent->type == FS_DT_DIR) {
                        printf("            %s/\n", dent->name);
                        ndirs++;
                } else if (dent->type == FS_DT_LNK) {
                        printf("    <SYM>   %s\n", dent->name);
                        nfiles++;
                } else {
                        printf(" %8lld   %s\n", dent->size, dent->name);
                        nfiles++;
                }
        }
```

So the number before the name is the filesize.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Was helpful in understanding a few commands on my Uboot command liine.